# What exactly does "reviewed" mean in the suspension messages?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-suspension

Once again, I have been locked out of reviews. I'm failing to understand the strict parameters for reviews here, but I've gone back to see what exactly is the issue. One of the questions I went back to was the [one listed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/33183932) It says I reviewed the question, but I'm not sure what that means.

If it means I passed it, that is simply not possible because I usually only filter R "first questions" and this question clearly does not contain anything related to R, which I would normally not pass. Some of the flagged reviews are from months ago so I can't really comment about the quality of my reviews going that far back, but I guess that can't be fixed. [This one is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/33183932) in that I would clearly have not just passed it but here it only says "reviewed."

Please help me get better. I try my best to look through these carefully, but I seem to always miss something by a marginal error.

Comment: It means you chose one of the "other actions" for the review (if you've chosen "looks OK" or "Share feedback", the UI would've displayed those review outcomes) - an unfortunate design limitation. I am not sure you can find out what the action was by yourself.

Comment: NP - IIRC, mods, if one chances to notice your posts, should be able to tell you the action they considered to be incorrect and why.

Comment: "*I usually only filter R "first questions" and this question clearly does not contain anything related to R*" the audit system will try to throw unrelated questions to you and pretend they are for the tag you filter by. So, when you were shown the audit, it probably had the [r] tag. You might have taken an action based on this (misleading) information.

Comment: This is an audit, so a test so see if you were paying attention. The system selected this post automatically because it's highly upvoted and expected you to perform a positive action on it (for example upvoting it or choosing Looks OK). You probably performed a negative action on it (for example flagging or downvoting), so the system considered you failed the audit and as a result banned you from review.

Comment: As others have pointed out, you are failing audits, on good valid questions, so anything other than "looks ok" in the example you provided would have resulted in a failure.  Review suspensions gradually increase in duration, so if you are "once again suspended from reviews" the likelihood is the duration is longer then it was previously unless a significant amount of time has passed. You linked to the same review twice. You should make a habit of opening, every question or answer you are reviewing, in another tab in your browser.

Comment: Isn't it weird to have a good question (chosen by the system) to be tagged with an unrelated tag? Wouldn't the only acceptable action be to edit the question, but this would fail the audit?

Comment: @Lino Editing known good audits passes the audit. I tested that [here](https://superuser.com/review/first-questions/1157322).